# Prime numbers of the form: $k\cdot 2^n \pm 1$ , where $k<3n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it true that :

> For every $n$ there exists a number $k<3n$ such that:
>
> $k\cdot 2^n-1$ or $k\cdot 2^n+1$ is prime,where $k,n\in \mathbf{N}$

Maple code that prints least $k$ such that  $k\cdot 2^n-1$ is prime and $k<3n$ :

[image]

for $n=624$ we have exception,there is no prime of the form $k\cdot 2^{624}-1$ such that $k<3\cdot 624$ , but  number  $85\cdot 2^{624}+1$ is prime number and $85<3\cdot 624$

Any idea how to prove or disprove statement above ?

Comment: Such numbers are called Sierpinski and Riesel numbers, respectively: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SierpinskiNumberoftheSecondKind.html, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RieselNumber.html

Comment: @JavaMan,What do you think,is there any other way to disprove this statement besides finding an counterexample ?

Comment: I have no intuition regarding your question.